# Performance issue during importing with Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a performance issue with my Core Data save.

I have about 10 Entities in my database where most of them are linked together with one-to-many relationships. After my import there are about 5000 objects in my database.

I optimized my import already by creating my own cache and therefore only having to do one fetch (to update existing data). That results into a super fast parsing of my API response.

But when my context now starts persisting to the hard drive, it's super slow on older phones (like iPhone 4).

So I started Instruments and had a look what might be wrong... but I don't know how to properly use the Core-Data Instrument.

I attached an screenshot of my Instruments. It seems that there are a lot of Core Data cache misses. The method `newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:` seems to be called a lot.

Any hints are very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: We need details. Background import? Replacing existing values? And so on...

Comment: Yes, it's a background import. And yes, it's replacing certain existing values. There are also some entities that get thrown away and are replaced (they don't have IDs when they come from the server and therefor can't be 'updated').
My import takes only a couple of ms, but then the save that is persisting to disk takes pretty long on an iPhone 4.

Comment: Mainly I was wondering what those core-data fetch misses are that are present in the screenshot i postet. I guess they are bad?!? And I'd like to know what I can do to get rid of them.

Comment: Btw. I use _MagicalRecords_ ``saveInBackground`` method for saving

Comment: Do you only save the context once, or do you save multiple times like at the end of a loop? Try saving your data periodically (like once every 500 managed object creates/updates) if you're not already.

Comment: Ah... ok... right now I save the context at the end of the complete import...
I'll have a look if saving it more often is helping me here.

At least the ``MagicalRecords`` ``saveInBackground:`` method is designed so that the save happens only at the end...

Can you tell me how i should/have to interpret my Instruments output? The middle instrument with the stars and checkmarks... What does it tell me?